# Generator quits after async() call

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I started learning about Yeoman generators and decided to try doing one myself following some tutorials. It's very basic but does what it's asked. My problem with it is, after I ask for user input for a name it simply quits/ends without going into writing any of the files, no errors just quits. I've isolated the possible culprit and it came down to the async() method because if I comment it out the generator runs well. I have other generators installed and they too use the same kind of prompt + async structure and I have no problems with those so I'm wondering what can I be doing wrong. Following is the index.js file:

```
'use strict';
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = yeoman.Base.extend({

  constructor: function () {
    // Calling the super constructor is important so our generator is correctly set up
    yeoman.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  prompting: function() {

    var done = this.async();
    this.prompt({
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'Whats the project name?',
      default: this.appname
    }, function(answers) {
      done();
    }.bind(this));

   this.props = {
     name: "yosass"
   };
  },

  writing: {
    //Copy the configuration files
    config: function() {
      this.log("CONFIG COPYING");
      this.props.name = "yosass";
      this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath('_package.json'),
        this.destinationPath('package.json'), {
          name: this.props.name
        }
      );

      this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath('_gulpfile.js'),
        this.destinationPath('gulpfile.js')
      )
    },

    //Copy application files
    app: function() {
      this.log("APP COPYING");
      this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath('_css/_main.scss'),
        this.destinationPath("css/main.scss")
      );

      this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath("_css/_globals/_variables.scss"),
        this.destinationPath("css/globals/_variables.scss")
      );

      this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath("_css/_globals/_mixins.scss"),
        this.destinationPath("css/globals/_mixins.scss")
      );

      this.fs.copy(
        this.templatePath("_css/_globals/_colors.scss"),
        this.destinationPath("css/globals/_colors.scss")
      );
    }
  },

  _copy: function(from, to) {
    this.fs.copy(this.templatePath(from), this.destinationPath(to));
  },

  _copyTpl: function(from, to) {
    this.fs.copy(this.templatePath(from), this.destinationPath(to));
  },

  //Install Dependencies
  install: function() {
    this.installDependencies();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.prompt` does not take a callback. It returns a promise.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Apparently the tutorial I was following was likely outdated because it clearly took a callback, all working as expected now.